# Getting POST data Play Framework (Java)

Tags: java, rest, post, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a Play application with a POST route which will act as a RESTful API.

Whats the best way to get POST data within a controller? As you can see from my controller I have attempted this, however it doesn't appear to work correctly.

Routes:

```
# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~

# Home page
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index()
GET     /api/getMessages            controllers.Application.getMessages()
POST    /api/createMessage          controllers.Application.createMessages()
```

Controller:

```
package controllers;

import play.*;
import play.mvc.*;
import static play.libs.Json.toJson;

import java.util.Map;

import models.*;

import views.html.*;

public class Application extends Controller {

    public static Result index() {
        return ok(index.render("Your new application is ready."));
    }

    public static Result createMessages(){
        final Map<String, String[]> values = request().body().asFormUrlEncoded();

        String from = values.get("from")[0];
        String subject = values.get("subject")[0]; 
        String message = values.get("message")[0];

        Message.create(from, subject, message);

        return ok(toJson("ok"));
    }

    public static Result getMessages(){
        return ok(toJson(Message.all()));
    }

}
```

Request:

```
Request Url: http://localhost:9000/api/createMessage
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 400
Params: {
    "from": "hello@test.com",
    "subject": "Hello",
    "message": "World"
}
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: The error returned is null

Answer (score 2):

Try with DynamicForm:

```
 public static Result createMessages(){
    DynamicForm df = play.data.Form.form().bindFromRequest();

    String from = df.get("from");
    String subject = df.get("subject");
    String message = df.get("message");

    if(from != null && subject != null && message != null){
        Message.create(from, subject, message);
        return ok(toJson("ok"));
    } else {
        return ok(toJson("error"));
    }


}
```

Comment: btw. form() is deprecated

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that author already found solution for those 2 years :), but today I was on same trouble and probably my nuance will help someone:

I used same methods to get POST parameters:

```
request().body().asFormUrlEncoded().get("from")[0];
```

And I got error too. But error was because of different POST type. So in my case I just was need to expect Multipart Form Data like in next variant:

```
request().body().asMultipartFormData().asFormUrlEncoded().get("from")[0];
```

So - just be a bit more careful with data that you are sending and data that you are expecting :)